# Skip executing <ui:include> when parent UI component is not rendered

Tags: jsf-2, include, facelets

I have the following construct at several places in my webapp in order to conditionally render page fragments depending on some actions:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{managedBean.serviceSelected == 'insurance'}">
    <ui:include src="/pages/edocket/include/service1.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

I have observed, that the `<ui:include>` is still executed even when the `rendered` attribute evaluates `false`. This unnecessarily creates all backing beans associated with the `service1.xhtml` file which is been included.

How can I skip executing the `<ui:include>` when the parent UI component is not rendered, so that all those backing beans are not unnecessarily created?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, this is by design. The `<ui:include>` runs as being a taghandler during the view build time, while the `rendered` attribute is evaluated during the view render time. This can be better understood by carefully reading this answer and substituting "JSTL" with "`<ui:include>`": [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

There are several ways to solve this, depending on the concrete functional requirement:

1. Use a view build time tag like `<c:if>` instead of `<h:panelGroup>`. This however puts implications into the `#{managedBean}`. It can't be view scoped and should do its job based on HTTP request parameters. Exactly those HTTP request parameters should also be retained in subsequent request (by e.g. `<f:param>`, `includeViewParams`, etc) so that it doesn't break when the view is restored.
2. Replace `<ui:include>` by a custom [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) which invokes [`FaceletContext#includeFacelet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext.html#includeFacelet%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29) during the [`UIComponent#encodechildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeChildren%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method. So far no such component exist in any of the existing libraries. But I can tell that I've already such one in mind as a future addition for [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) and it works as intuitively expected here at my test environment (with Mojarra). Here's a kickoff example:

   ```
   @FacesComponent(Include.COMPONENT_TYPE)
   public class Include extends UIComponentBase {

       public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "com.example.Include";
       public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "com.example.Output";

       private enum PropertyKeys {
           src;
       }

       @Override
       public String getFamily() {
           return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean getRendersChildren() {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
           getChildren().clear();
           FaceletContext faceletContext = ((FaceletContext) context.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY));
           faceletContext.includeFacelet(this, getSrc());
           super.encodeChildren(context);
       }

       public String getSrc() {
           return (String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.src);
       }

       public void setSrc(String src) {
           getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.src, src);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply BaluSC . But Iam not able to understand the answer.  Where we need to declare this component and how to use it.

Comment: Hi Balusc ,  after adding the component the skipping of include is happening perfectly.    But when it is required to be included , that time fails .  I will paste the exception FYI .

Comment: Has this been included in omnifaces yet, BalusC?

Comment: @Thang: No, this construct didn't work in MyFaces (and beyond some extent also not in Mojarra). See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680192/dynamic-ajax-navigation-with-uiinclude/13723755#13723755

Comment: @BalusC: So does this mean that if we want dynamic include, we have to make the bean SessionScoped, BalusC?

Answer (score 7):

Use conditional expression as ui:include src:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <ui:include 
        src="#{managedBean.serviceSelected == 'insurance' ?
            '/pages/edocket/include/service1.xhtml'
            :
            '/pages/empty.xhtml'}"
    />
</h:panelGroup>
```