# Launching dialogs using PrimeFaces via <p:dialog> and <ui:include>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces UI library for my web UI project.

I have a `manage_watchfolder.xhtml` page that has a button, and this button launches a dialog:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" oncomplete="dlgEditWF.show()"
    update=":editWFForm" process="@none"/>
```

Inside this same file I have `dlgEditWF` included from `edit_watchfolder.xhtml`:

```
<p:dialog id="editDialog" widgetVar="dlgEditWF" modal="true"
    resizable="true" onShow="showHideActionLocation();">
    <ui:include src="edit/edit_watchfolder.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
```

The problem is that I do not want `edit_watchfolder.xhtml` to be **loaded** before the button is clicked. However, `edit_watchfolder.xhtml` is "loaded" at the same moment `manage_watchfolder.xhtml` is created. So, all the beans called from `edit_watchfolder.xhtml` are created, initialized, etc, even user maybe will never actually click on the button. This creates a lot of overhead, and makes execution slow.

Can I avoid this?

Comment: You can find the solution in this answer by BalusC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989631/skip-executing-uiinclude-when-parent-ui-component-is-not-rendered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "dynamic" attribute of `p:dialog`. Have a look at the primefaces [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogDynamic.jsf).

```
<p:commandButton id="basic" value="Show Dialog" onclick="dlg.show();" type="button" />  

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dynamic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" dynamic="true">  
    <h:outputText value="This content is loaded lazy." />  
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: @BalusC Different problem now: first time that I launch the dialog - backing bean gets created twice. After I close the dialog, and launch again it creates bean only once, and continues creating it once like it should and then works ok. So only problem is FIRST launch. Why does the bean get created twice this first time?

Answer (score 5):

This is "by design" for the reasons explained in this answer: [Skip executing <ui:include> when parent UI component is not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989631/skip-executing-uiinclude-when-parent-ui-component-is-not-rendered/11991895#11991895).

In your particular case, your best bet is to leave the bean uninitialized by default and perform initialization during the command button's action method instead.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.initDialog}" 
    process="@this" update=":editWFForm" oncomplete="dlgEditWF.show()" />
```

Comment: But my "parent" page and pop-up dialog use **the same** bean. :-(

Comment: I'm not sure how that forms a problem if you invoke the dialog's initialization by action method only.

Comment: Because my parent page needs the bean initialized. My pop-up page needs the been uninitialized. If I move the initialization from contructor to initDialog(), then how will my parent page get initialized bean?

Comment: Just do parent page initialization in bean (post)constructor and dialog initialization in action method? They do not need to take place in one and same method.

Comment: Problem is that when dialog creates bean it will do parent-page initialization. I can't skip parent page initialization in this case (post construct as you say), can I?

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. Obviously I need two different inits, one for parent page, and other for dialog, mutualy exclusive. Dialog one `initDialog()` I can do with button action, but "default" one will be called for both unfortunately?

Comment: The (post)constructor is only invoked when the bean is constructed by JSF. I'm not sure how/why that's a problem. You want that the default page still works, right?

Comment: Btw, my bean is request scoped.

Comment: I need to avoid "default" constructor when dialog "creates" the bean, that is, before I press the button and call `initDialog()` action. Is that possible?

Comment: If you do that, then the chance is big that `<p:commandButton>` fails to do its job (for sure when it's placed inside e.g. a data table). Can't you just put the bean in the view scope?

Comment: no I can't use view scope because I would need to serialize everything... not doable

Comment: If you're absolutely positive that the bean doesn't need to be initialized for the parent page during a postback, then add a check if you're in a postback or not.

Comment: Maybe I just do different beans for dialog and parent? Parent bean would extend from the dialog bean, and it would add some stuff that I don't want in the dialog bean. Does that make sense?

Comment: While a better design, that would functionally not make any difference. The bean associated with the parent page would still be constructed/initialized when you submit the parent page's form, because it's a new request and the bean is request scoped. Depending on the specific functional requirement, it would maybe work for you if you make the dialog lazy loading (`dynamic="true"`) and if you use `<p:button>` instead of `<p:commandButton>` so that you don't submit the form.