# Conditional jsf include

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, user-interface, include

How can I conditionally include a jsf facelets file at runtime?
sample functionality required is

```
if ( add button click) {

ui:include src="Add.xhtml"
}

if ( update button click) {

ui:include src="Update.xhtml"
}
```

the syntax above is only indicative ...

**Mojarra 2.1.1 / Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 / PrimeFaces 3.4**

Answer (score 7):

`ui:include` doesn't have `rendered` attribute, so you have to encapsulate it in some other component. Also, you will set some property on server base on button clicked.

```xml
<h:form>
  <p:commandButton value="Add" update=":includeContainer">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="add" target="#{myBean.action}"/>
  </p:commandButton>
  <p:commandButton value="Update" update=":includeContainer">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="update" target="#{myBean.action}"/>
  </p:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="includeContainer">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.action == 'add'}">
    <ui:include src="add.xhtml"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.action == 'update'}">
    <ui:include src="update.xhtml"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

in backing bean you will have getter and setter:

```java
public void setAction(String action) {
  this.action = action;
}

public String getAction() {
  return action;
}
```

Comment: a substitute question to this is that if its a conditional include then why is the xhtml processed when the main file is called ... i checked this by including a f:event prerenderview tag in the add.xhtml file for example ... i get the system.out printed via the listener method <f:event listener="#{bean.method1}" type="preRenderView"> ... yes the view scoped bean is not instantiated but the xhtml is parsed and prerenderview event triggered ... why is it so when its a conditional include?

Comment: This is because `ui:include` is executed during build view phase, and rendered attribute is calculated later during render view phase. That is the way this works in JSF. If this is a problem you must consider another solutions. Consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989631/skip-executing-uiinclude-when-parent-ui-component-is-not-rendered/11991895#11991895) for solutions.

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i repost the answer of partlov becaus have some error and i corect this errors an put in this pos, and congratulatiosn partlov to much good answer

i complement your answer
first this is a xhtml page whith prime faces, if you want use a p: add this frameworc or an other.

if you wont download this framewor doenload here[Download prime Framework for JSF](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html)

and impor for this way

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

**select.XHTML**

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Add" update="panel">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="add" target="#{myBean.action}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton value="Update" update="panel">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="update" target="#{myBean.action}"/>
    </p:commandButton>


    <h:panelGroup id="panel">
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.action == 'add'}">
        <ui:include src="headerLogin.xhtml"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.action == 'update'}">
        <ui:include src="Pajax.xhtml"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

nex step is a create a clas myBean and use this string for a select whath UI you want render
**myBean.java**

use this imports in a bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

and use this cod in a clas

```
public class myBean {
String action;
public void setAction(String action) {

    this.action = action;
}

public String getAction() {
  return action;
}
```

}

but remember put this line up to a class

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
```

Comment: Is this example working? I copy pasted the code and tried but it didn't work as expected. I need to refresh the page to go on next option. Any help is appreciated.